# Turboprop: Specific thrust as a function of two independent parameters

Tags: mechanical-engineering

The following turboprop arrangement is given (see picture below). It has a single shaft, and all stages have been numbered (from "a" to "8").

[image: Turboprop-Single-Shaft]

**PROBLEM:**

I am asked to express the specific thrust in terms of $\theta\left(\equiv\dfrac{T_{03}}{T_a}\right)$, $\pi_c\left(\equiv\dfrac{p_{03}}{p_{02}}\right)$, and the ambient conditions (pressure $p_a$, temperature $T_a$, flight speed $U$).

---

**INFORMATION/DATA AVAILABLE FOR THIS PROBLEM**

- Nozzle is choked ($p_8=p_a$) and it develops NO thrust ($u_8=U$, that is, the gas velocity at the exit matches the flight speed, $U$).
- Flight speed, $U$.
- Turboprop components are *NOT IDEAL*, therefore all efficiencies are given: shaft, **t**urbine, **c**ompressor, **g**earbox, **p**ropeller, **b**urner and **d**iffuser ($\eta_{m}$,$\eta_{t}$,$\eta_{c}$,$\eta_{g}$,$\eta_{p}$,$\eta_{b}$,$\eta_{d}$, respectively).
- Ideal gas ($\gamma$, $c_p$ are constant throughout the main engine core).
- Fuel heating value is known ($Q_r$).
- Propeller work coefficient is known ($C_{wP}$).
- Ambients conditions are known ($T_a$, $p_a$, $U$).

---

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $p_8=p_a$ and $u_8=U$, the total thrust developed is: $$F=\dot{m_f}U+F_{p}$$ where:

- $\dot{m_f}$ is the fuel mass flow rate.
- $F_{p}$ is the thrust developed by the propeller.

I am being asked for the specific thrust, that is: $$F_s\equiv\dfrac{F}{\dot{m}}$$$$\boxed{F_s=f\cdot U+\dfrac{F_{p}}{\dot{m}}}$$ where we have introduced a parameter: $f\equiv \dot{m_f}/\dot{m}$, known as *fuel ratio*. Note that the fuel ratio here is the only unknown quantity, since $$\dfrac{F_{p}}{\dot{m}}=\dfrac{\frac1U \dot{m}c_pT_a\eta_pC_{wP}}{\dot{m}}=\dfrac{c_pT_a\eta_pC_{wP}}{U}$$ is all known from the data available.

Therefore, we need to come up with an expression that relates the fuel ratio, $f$, with $\theta$ and $\pi_c$ (and with the ambien conditions, of course). Remember again that $\theta\equiv\dfrac{T_{03}}{T_a}$ and $\pi_c\equiv\dfrac{p_{03}}{p_{02}}$.

To achieve this, I decide to use the energy balance on the burner, to find that:
$$\boxed{f=\dfrac{h_{04}-h_{03}}{\eta_bQ_r-h_{04}}=\dfrac{c_p\left(T_{04}-\theta T_a\right)}{\eta_bQ_r-c_pT_{04}}}$$

In this last expression, all of the parameters are known **except** $T_{04}$. Note that this temperature, *known as the stagnation temperature at the turbine inlet*, is usually a design parameter (and is *usually* allowed to be used as a parameter in the resulting expression of $F_s$). However this is not the case for the present problem, in which we will need to write $T_{04}$ in terms of (again) $\theta$, $\pi_c$ and the ambient conditions.

So I proceed to apply the energy balance on the shaft, to relate powers: $$\dot{W_T}=-\dfrac{1}{\eta_m}\dot{W_C}-\dfrac{1}{\eta_m \eta_g}\dot{W_P}$$ From the definition of the propeller efficiency, we know that: $\dot{W_P}=\eta_p\dot{W_P}^{\text{ideal}}=\eta_p\dot{m}c_pT_aC_{wP}$, and therefore this term is known from the given data. So we can say that: $$h_{04}-h_{05}=\dfrac{1}{\eta_m}\left(h_{03}-h_{02}\right)+\dfrac{\eta_p}{\eta_m \eta_g}c_pC_{wP}\dot{m}T_a$$ Since the diffuser is considered to be adiabatic, we can rest assured that: $T_{02}/T_a=1+U^2/\left(2c_pT_a\right)$, a known quantity. This allows us to algebraically manipulate the former equation to obtain: $$\boxed{T_{04}=c_pT_a\left[\dfrac{T_{05}}{T_a}+\dfrac{1}{\eta_m}\left(\theta-\dfrac{U^2}{2c_pT_a}-1\right)+\dfrac{\eta_p}{\eta_m \eta_g}c_pC_{wP}\dot{m} \right]}$$

Again, a new parameter arises: $T_{05}$. Remember that this is the total temperature at the nozzle inlet (or the turbine exit). But since the nozzle is adiabatic, we can state that: $$T_{05}=T_{08}\Longrightarrow T_{05}=T_8\left(1+\dfrac{\gamma-1}{2}M_8^2\right)=\ldots=T_8\left(1+\dfrac{U^2}{2c_pT_8}\right)$$ Therefore: $$\boxed{T_{05}=T_8+\dfrac{U^2}{2c_p}}$$

Here is where I stop. Note that $T_8$ is unknown, and needs to be related with $\theta$, $\pi_c$ and the triad $\{T_a, p_a, U\}$. It is worth noting that the parameter $\pi_c$ hasn't been used yet, which suggests me to follow a reverse flow-path approach.

So: how do I find $T_8$ here (temperature at the nozzle exit), and how do I account for the remaining design parameter, $\pi_c$?

Comment: Hi @OSUZorba. Do you by any chance know if I'm allowed to copy&paste this exact same question in that forum? Or is there a way to move this question from this forum to that other one? Thanks.

Comment: It is frowned upon to post the same question on two SEs. You can flag the post and ask a mod to move it, or you can repost it there and delete this question.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it'd be frowned upon. I flagged it and asked a moderator to move it to the "engineering" SE.